# Saga Compensating Transaction

Tags: microservices, saga

Currently working on initial phase of Microservice Architecture for product. It is evident that for many operation it required to have distributed transaction or say there are couple of operation required across different microservice in-order to complete one business process.

For this purpose I found that Saga is useful. Now for ideal case or where everything goes correct then it works fine but when something is not correct or some activity failed at that moment we may have to rollback those operation. For this there is something called "Compensating" transaction or operation required. Now It is completely possible when operation performed specially for successful operation, it may possible that other transaction also performed on that service so db might be in different state then when actually operation performed.

What will be the solution for this ? One solution I think is that somehow state needs to preserve so it can revisit but like for stock may be change to some other transaction so I feel that compensating transaction would be a problem.

Comment: This completely depends on the application domain (and is therefore not a good fit for the Stack Overflow format). It's helpful to go through the thought exercise of how you would compensate if the transaction were processed manually and there was a mistake. For example, if you buy too much of  something, you can sell some of it. If you withdraw too much from an account, you can refund it. If you send an email with a mistake in it, you can send another email with a correction and an apology.

Comment: Check out NServiceBus's documentation around Sagas: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/

Hope this helps